# Creating layout for user leave-intent

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, cursor-position

I want to understand how to capture user intent i.e. when a user decides to leave the page and moves his/her mouse (as of now), show them an alternate version (without refresh).

An [example](http://housing.com/in/mumbai/rent/search/125015?f=eyJuZWFyYnkiOnsibGF0IjoxOS4xNTc5MzUsImxuZyI6NzIuOTkzNDc2MjAwMDAwMDMsInJhZCI6MzAwMCwibmFtZSI6IkFpcm9saSwgTmF2aSBNdW1iYWkiLCJwb2ludF9pZCI6IjZlNjU4OTlmY2MwODEyMmU5Y2VlODVkMTIyNDAxMjE3Y2JiMjUyNzAifSwiYXBhcnRtZW50X3R5cGVzIjpbM10sIm1hcF9hcnJhbmdlIjoibGlmZXN0eWxlX3JhdGluZyIsInNvcnRfa2V5IjoibGlmZXN0eWxlX3JhdGluZyIsInNvcnRfb3JkZXIiOiJmYWxzZSJ9)

When you open this page, it will show you a couple of listings. Now, if you move your mouse to the address bar again. It hides the content and shows a separate part of the layout, basically a modal window with some messaging.

Is it handled via javascript - detect the cursor position and change the layout.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using document mouseleave and mouseenter you can achieve this.

```
$(document).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('#test').removeClass('disnone');
}).on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('#test').addClass('disnone');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/p3fKd/1/)